# texdoc giving error when try to open manual

Tags: texdoc

When i used the command `texdoc pgfplots` it gives me an error of

"Error (0): Call to Object where the object was type 13, not the expected type 7"

when i used texdoc tikz it gives the pdf manual

Comment: What version of `texdoc` do you have? (`texdoc --version`) I have version 2.017 on TeX Live 2017 and it works fine for me.

Comment: I am using texdoc 2.0171 @NicolaTalbot

Comment: Run `texdoc --help` which will list the environment variables, such as `PDFVIEWER`, used by `texdoc`. Check the value and try running that command directly on the path name returned with `texdoc -l pgfplots`. It may be that the error message is coming from the viewer application rather than `texdoc`.

Comment: still not working giving same problem@NicolaTalbot

Comment: What is `PDFVIEWER` set to? Is the problem just with `pgfplots` or does it happen with other packages as well?

Answer (score 1):

first check for the pgfplots.pdf file

```
texdoc -s pgfplots
 1 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf
   = Package manual
```

second try for a pdf viewer to open pgfplots.pdf

then check

```
  PDFVIEWER=<pdfreader> texdoc pgfplot
```

finally you report the pdf reader in your texdoc.cnf file.

texdoc -f
will display the list of texdoc configuration files

Comment: Not working@gigiair

Comment: does the pgfplots.pdf exists ?

Comment: yes it is exist @gigiair

Comment: texdoc 2.0171 on my Debian buster box works fine. There must be a local problem on your machine.

Comment: may be, thanking you very much for your comments@gigiair